# Error: ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am compiling a code that I have downloaded. while making the files using CmakeList, I am getting the following error in this line of code:

```
VocTree::findPath(Mat &descriptor) {

    list<int> path;
    int idNode = 0;
    unsigned int numCh = _k;

    path.push_back(idNode);

    while (!isLeaf(idNode)) {

        //Search the closest sub-cluster
        int idClosest = 0;
        double minDist = numeric_limits<int>::max();

        for (size_t i = 0; i < numCh; i++) {

            int childId = idChild(idNode, i);
            int idxChild = _index[childId];
            double d = norm(descriptor, _centers.row(idxChild), _useNorm);

            if (i == 0 || d < minDist) {
                minDist = d;
                idClosest = childId;
            }

        }

        idNode = idClosest;
        path.push_back(idNode);
    }

    return path;

}
```

This is the error:

```
src/VocTree.cpp:872:26: error: ‘numeric_limits’ was not declared in this scope
         double minDist = numeric_limits<int>::max();
                          ^
src/VocTree.cpp:872:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
         double minDist = numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

The following namespaces have been used:

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

Comment: `#include <limits>`

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not a substitute for `#include`s. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115556/c-using-namespace-and-include).

Comment: @S.EB That's an entirely different error that belongs either as a new question or possibly as an issue on the GitHub (or equivalent) of the code you've downloaded.

Comment: @S.EB That's a different question and shouldn't be asked as part of this one. Before posting that question, please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show what you've attempted to solve it yourself first as part of that question.

Comment: @S.EB It looks like it can't read some file. Maybe your installation is corrupt? Try following the instructions again carefully.

Comment: @S.EB Assertion failed with `core dumped` is runtime error. Which is unrelated to your initial question relating to failing compilation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for your comment, I am not expert in C++ and OpenCV. Could I ask, should I remove `using namespace std;` and replace with `include`?

Comment: @S.EB `#include` and `using namespace std;` work independently and do different things. Neither is a replacement for the other. See the question I previously linked, this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115556/c-using-namespace-and-include

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks for your help. The problem solved by including `limits` in both header file and `cpp` files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include

```
    #include <limits>
```

Comment: Thanks . Should I remove `using namespace std` ?

Comment: @S.EB No, std namespace used for list<int> path;

Comment: Thanks I could solve it by ` #include <limits>`